# hover , смена свойств у другого объекта

Tags: css

Подскажите, как изменить свойства другого объетка через `hover`?
В моём случае поставить `visibility` на `visible`.
Я предполагал как то так :

```
.reiss-text: hover > .reiss-ramka {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Для чего это? Какого поведения пытаетесь получить?

Comment: Есть 2 блока. 1 скрыт. Навели курсором на блок > второй блок сдал видимым

Comment: Я обычно использую свойство display: none;

Comment: Например в выпадающем меню li:hover > ul {display: block;}

Comment: Я не знаю почему, но у меня не получается .reiss-ramka
{
visibility:  hidden;
 display:block;
 width: 216px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: #00a388;
 margin-top: -66px;
} .reiss-text: hover +.reiss-ramka {
 visibility: visible;
 }

Comment: Не важно что у меня блок невидимый - div , а навожу курсор на техт - span, ???

Answer (score 1):

У Вас не получается из-за того, что Вы hover добавляете через пробел:

```
.reiss-text: hover +.reiss-ramka
```

Это не правильная запись. Нужно писать - `:hover`!

И вот Ваш же пример:

```css
.reiss-ramka { 
  visibility: hidden; 
  display:block; 
  width: 216px; 
  height: 300px; 
  background-color: #00a388; 
  margin-top: -66px; 
} 

.reiss-text:hover +.reiss-ramka { 
  visibility: visible; 
}
```

```html
  <div class="reiss-text">reiss-text</div>
  <div class="reiss-ramka">reiss-ramka</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 варианта с `display` и `visibility`

```css
div.b {
    display: none;
}

div.a:hover + div.b {
    display: block;
}

div.d {
    visibility: hidden;
}

div.c:hover + div.d {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">Видимый</div>
<div class="b">Скрытый display: none</div>
<div class="c">Видимый</div>
<div class="d">Скрытый visibility: hidden</div>
```